# iOSのArchivesビルド後のvalidationでエラー。arm64とiOS5は同時にサポートできない？

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

XcodeでiTunes Connectへアプリケーションを提出する際、Valideの段階で次のエラーが表示されました。

> this bundle is invalid.
>   apps that include arm64 architecture cannot have Minimum OSversion set to less than 5.1.1.
>   more information about 64-bit support for iOS is available at 64-bit transition guide for cocoa touch at developer.apple.com.

SDKはiOS 8.1、Deployment Targetは5.0です。

64bitアーキテクチャ(iPhone 5s以降)とiOS 5向けに同時に対応することはできないのでしょうか？

これはiTunesConnectへ提出時のエラーです。 xocdeのメニューのproductでarchiveでビルドし、そのあとに提出用のダイアログ(organizer)が表示され、そこでvalidationを押した時のチェックでエラーになりまし‌​た。 その前までは各種シュミレータやデバイスのテストで同様のエラーは出ていません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arm64を削除する手段が2015年2月までは合ったようですが、
現在その方法が通用するかどうかという問題と、arm64を削除すると当然ながら実機iPhone6などでは動作しません。
それでは困るので、仕方ないのでメッセージの指示通りにGeneralの設定のDeployment Targetを「5.1.1」に指定(自分で書いた)しました。これでvalidationは通りました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参考情報: [About 64-Bit Cocoa Touch Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)（[日本語版PDF](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/CocoaTouch64BitGuide.pdf)）

> Xcode 5.0.1では、32ビット/64ビットのどちらにも対応したアプリケーションを構築できます。ただし、この混成バイナリが動作するのはiOS 5.1.1以降です。