# iOSアプリ公開時のApp Storeでの旧バージョンのダウンロードについて

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone

2月からiOSアプリの64bit対応が義務付けられ、遅ればせながら当方のアプリも64bit対応を行いました。
しかし、App Storeに64bit/32bitの混在アプリを公開する場合は、Deployment TargetをiOS 5.1.1以降にする必要があるという[情報を見ました](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7364/ios%E3%81%AEarchives%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%AEvalidation%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC-arm64%E3%81%A8ios5%E3%81%AF%E5%90%8C%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E3%82%B5%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)。
当方のアプリはiOS 4.3を使っているユーザーも居るため、旧バージョンのアプリも引き続きダウンロード可能な状態にしたいと思っています。

そこで、古いiOSでアプリをダウンロードしようとすると「この App の旧バージョンをダウンロードしますか？」と表示されるアプリ(Chromeなど)がありますが、これは、開発者側は特に何もしなくても実現できる機能なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

はい。App Store（もしくはiTunes Connect）が各バージョンごとのipaを保持しています。サポート対象外となった端末でダウンロードを試みると、そのバージョンがサポートされていたipaがダウンロードされます。ただし、ダウンロード可能なのは、そのアプリを過去に一度でもダウンロードしたことがある端末（Apple アカウント）のみです。